# Could not bind properties to 'DataSource' Springboot 2.7.9

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have upgraded springboot from 2.2.3.RELEASE to 2.7.9, then datasource bean creation started throwing below exception

Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'primaryDataSource': Could not bind properties to 'DataSource' : prefix=app.datasource.primary, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'app.datasource.primary' to javax.sql.DataSource"

the properties I have in config are below

```
app:
  datasource:
    primary:
      minimum-idle: 5
      maximum-pool-size: 20
      connection-timeout: 30000
      maxLifetime: 540000
      idleTimeout: 30000
      url: "jdbc:mysql://url"
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      username: user
      password: pwd
```

bean method

```
@Bean(name = "primaryDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.primary")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
```

Dependencies

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

The same setup works with 2.2.X spring boot version, what I am missing

Comment: I think you are using hikari jdbc datasource here, and some of your properties are not being mapped correctly to your given properties.
following are some mandatory ones : `url,driverClassName,username,password`
ref: `org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder.DataSourceProperty`
ensure you have correct naming else it will fail.

In exception you might be able to see which exact property caused problems

Comment: I have all those field on the config as mentioned and its working good with older version of springboot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have mentioned the jdbc url in config as
`url: "jdbc:mysql://url"` it need to be updated as
`jdbc-url: "jdbc:mysql://url"`